# Exclude some attributes from fields method of dataclass

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a python `dataclass` that looks something like:

```
@dataclass
class MyDataClass:
    field0: int = 0
    field1: int = 0

    # --- Some other attribute that shouldn't be considered as _fields_ of the class
    attr0: int = 0
    attr1: int = 0
```

I'd like to write the class in such a way that, when calling `dataclasses.fields(my_data:=MyDataClass())`, only `field0` and `field1` are reported.

As a workaround, I've splitted the class in two inheriting classes, as:

```
@dataclass
class MyData:
    field0: int = 0
    field1: int = 0

class MyDataClass(MyData):
    # --- Some other attribute that shouldn't be considered as _fields_ of the class
    attr0: int = 0
    attr1: int = 0
```

It works, but I don't know if it's the right way (some drawback I'm not considering?) or if there is a more straightforward way to do it

Comment: Are you looking for `InitVar`? There are lots of ways that the behavior of `attr0` and `attr1` can differ than just being absent from the return value of `fields`.

Comment: it's a little unclear what you mean. do you mean to init `field1` from `attr1`, for example?

Comment: @rv.kvetch, I wrote exactly what I need: 'attr1' and `attr2` to be excluded from fields list when invoking `fields` function. That's in both the title and the question

Comment: right, but you can just as easily exclude them from the field list by removing anntation, for ex. like `attr0 = 0`; that's what I meant by a bit more clarification could be useful.

Comment: That's another good possibility I did not know. Thank you, though I could not clarify better what was not in my mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, but you may declare the non-field attributes as `InitVar[int]` and set them in a `__post_init__()` method.

```
@dataclass
class MyDataClass:
    field0: int = 0
    field1: int = 0

    # --- Some other attribute that shouldn't be considered as _fields_ of the class
    attr0: InitVar[int] = 0
    attr1: InitVar[int] = 0
    
    def __post_init__(self, attr0, attr1):
        self.attr0 = attr0
        self.attr1 = attr1
```

Comment: I'll try this solution soon, but I think it's exactly what I needed. Thank you