# Type hint extra attributes (not fields)

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, python-dataclasses

This is *almost* a duplicate of [Exclude some attributes from fields method of dataclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73560307).

I have a `dataclass` that needs some extra attributes, which should not be considered as fields, that are derived from the fields during `__post_init__`. (In particular, they are not `InitVar`'s!)

Since I type check my code, I want to add type hints for these attributes:

```py
@dataclass
class MyDataClass:
    field0: int
    field1: int
    
    _: KW_ONLY
    
    fieldN: int

    # internal/derived attribute that shouldn't be considered as _fields_
    attr0: int  # we still want type hints for obvious reasons!
    attr1: int  # These are not InitVars!
```

However, this will make them fields. I tried adding single/double underscores, which didn't work. I considered making these `@properties`, but then where would you type hint the necessary `self._attr0`? I guess a `@cached_property` could work, but it's an unsatisfying answer.

Comment: Just curious, what’s the use of instance attributes on a dataclass that aren’t dataclass fields? Any particular thing that you want disabled, or?

Comment: @dROOOze I am writing some data encoders (similar to [`scikit-learn` estimators](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html)), for which certain internal attributes are only available after calling `encoder.fit(data)` once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since dataclasses make real use in runtime of the typed variables, and you just want these to be set at static type checking time, probably the simplest idea is declare the fields in a way they are only "seen" at type-checking time.

This way, the dataclass machinery won't know about them and won't create the fields, but when using them, the static type-checking tools will. The constante `type.TYPE_CHECKING` can be used for such a declaration:

```
import typing
from dataclasses import dataclass

...

@dataclass
class MyDataClass:
    field0: int
    field1: int
    
    _: KW_ONLY
    
    fieldN: int

    if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
        # internal/derived attribute that shouldn't be considered as _fields_
        attr0: int  # we still want type hints for obvious reasons!
        attr1: int  # These are not InitVars!
```

So, while that would be straightforward, from the feedback in the comments, it looks like the special-casing mypy uses to figure out dataclasses simply assume these are fields anyway, and require them to be present when instantiating `MyDataClass`.

While it would be possible to create a mechanism to remove the fields from the class body and annotation before calling the `@dataclass` decorator, by creating an intermediary decorator - that would not help either: again, the fields would be visible to MyPy and it would require those to be present when creating the class, not knowing they are real fields.

Just make them properties, and for type-hinting the inner `self._attr0` attribute, just allow typing inference to do it, or `typing.cast` to force it when setting:

```
class MyDataclass:
    ...

    def __post_init__(self):
        self._attr0 = ... # expression using existing parameters and attributes. 
            # Static typing _SHOULD_ know how to infer its type.       # but if it does not, force the type with cast:
         self._attr0 = typing.cast(int, <expression>) 

    @property
    def attr0(self) -> int:
         return self._attr0
```

Comment: This is a good attempt, unfortunately it seems like [MyPy still thinks these are fields required at `__init__`](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=66eea4cd463bf0ee6aa04cd43d642e6c), and raises `[call-arg]` whenever initializing the class, complaining about missing `attr0`.

Comment: well... this is the kind of thing that happens when trying to strap static typing to a dynamic language. They special cased mypy so it can figure out dataclasses, but it is still unable, and will remain so, to understand any edge cases.

Comment: the thing will be to go the other way around - -just a second.

Comment: Honestly, I feel like the problem is also at least partially with `dataclass`. They could simply provide a sentinel similar to `KW_ONLY`, after which all attributes are ignored.

Comment: This is an static-typing problem. Dataclasses is just fine. And, even if dataclasses would create sucha  snetinel, the special-case for the sentinel would have to be created _also_ inside MyPy, or it would still think the other attributes are fields. Given that a mechanism for dataclass not create the fields exists, in the form I provided in the first snippet in this answer, the fault is with static checking tools

Comment: `if TYPE_CHECKING` couldn't work: such block is "`mypy` sees this as present unconditionally (no real if/else branches), while runtime does the opposite" - not "hey `mypy`, this is just for you, but you know it is not there IRL". (property solution is great, upvote is yours)

Comment: Yes - that is exactly the initial idea: MYPY see the fields, and type check then as class attributes, while the runtime does not see the fields, and does not add then to the dataclass (exactly what is requested in the O.P.)

What fails is that MYPY special cases dataclasses and adds each class attribute in there to its expected signature to the class's `__init__`. 
Not sure if adding a `dataclass.field` with the ` field=False` argument would fix that (it would depend on the mypy/static tool specialization being able to understand that option as well)

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate the non-fields on `self` inside `__post_init__`:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, KW_ONLY

@dataclass
class MyDataClass:
    field0: int
    field1: int

    _: KW_ONLY

    fieldN: int

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        self.attr0: int
        self.attr1: int


data = MyDataClass(1, 2, fieldN=3)  # OK - no specifying `attr0` or `attr1`
attr0: str = data.attr0  # mypy: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", variable has type "str") [assignment]
data.attr1 = ""  # mypy: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "int") [assignment]
```